A solution to an equation on trigonometric functions
Consider the equation
$$
2 \sin 2x + \cot \frac{(n-1)x}{2} = 0
$$
on $x$ for fixed positive integer $n$.
Is there an explicit solution or an approximate solution for $x$ in each interval $(\frac{2k\pi}{n-1},\frac{2(k+1)\pi}{n-1})$, where $k$ is a nonnegative integer.
Yes, previously I ever draw in graph about the function $2 \sin 2x + \cot \frac{(n-1)x}{2}$ with small $n$ (see attached figure below). What I can observe are as following:

The graph would be partitioned into seveal parts, say $(\frac{2k \pi}{n-1}, \frac{2(k+1) \pi}{n-1})$ for integer $k$, which can be seen from the unboundness of the $\cot$ funtion at the extreme points of such intervals.

The function $2 \sin 2x + \cot \frac{(n-1)x}{2}$ is a periodic function, which is due the periodicity of $\sin$ and $\cot$.

We can see exactly exacly one root of $2 \sin 2x + \cot \frac{(n-1)x}{2} = 0$ lying on each interval $(\frac{2k\pi}{n-1},\frac{2(k+1)\pi}{n-1})$, where $k$ is an integer, except the possible root $x = \pi$ and some other related roots due ot the periodicity.

What I want to work is the explicit or approximate solutions for such roots.


enter image description here

Your equation is missing an equals.

Have you drawn the graphical representation of corresponding functions $f_n(x)$ for moderate values of $n$ (with Geogebra for example : it is so easy !) in order to have an idea (yes/no) of the answer to be given to the question ?

Are you trying to find the zeros of this function? If so, as @eyeballfrog says, you're missing an equals sign. As it stands, this is not an equation.

I agree with the previous comments, and wish to discuss the comment of Jean Marie.  Although visualizing the problem will not immediately lead to a solution to the problem, it will expand your intuition, which will (I believe) help you attack the problem.  You might then still be unable to solve the problem, but expanding your intuition here is generally always a good idea.  I encourage you to find some math-graphical software, and obtain a computer generated graph of the pertinent function.

Sorry, I missed "= 0 " before, now it is added.
